How to fill a loop?
How should I go about filling this area between these two edges? Because it's a loop, I can't just make it one face, but how should I go about filling it as smaller faces?






You already have the bottom face. It would be the same for the top face. So why not just delete the vertices at the top and extrude the shape again upwards?

The bottom face is leftover from a different method I tried, it didn't work well at all so I'm trying other options

Harry McKenzie'suggestion is the simplest way to do what you want (extrude the bottom). But if you really want to fill the part, use AltF then if you want to simplify the topology, press X > Limited Dissolve:

Edit: For your current object, use a Smooth by Angle modifier to fix the shading:

And rearrange the topology a bit:


These suggestions work well, but there is another problem I end up encountering. after I fix overlapping vertices and shade smooth, there's a lot of artifacting going on. The way I'd usually deal with this would be to just inset the face, but because I have 2 faces, insetting both causes more artifacting. Using smooth by angle also won't work as I need to bevel the edges of the mesh as well. It's a complex problem, but is there anything obvious I could do to fix some of these issues?

Hello could you please highlight the artefacts you are talking about? Edit your original post with some new screenshots

The screenshots have been added, along with a new blend file

I've edited my answer

Thanks, but how did you do that topology change? Are you using an old version of the file

Use the knife tool (K), the join (J), the dissolve edges (Ctrl X), etc....    ;)

Since your origin is already right in the center of your object you can just use Mesh > Symmetrize with the direction set to -Z to +Z.


Result:

If you had a more asymmetrical mesh and you needed to fill the face in manually then you just need to fill in a little bit of the face first:


Then doing the rest is pretty easy.


These are just a couple of the options. What others are posting too are absolutely valid. There's alot of different ways to do this kind of thing.

As I mentioned before, the bottom face is a remnant of a different method I tried which posed a lot of issues. I'll go through these suggestions and see what works, thanks
